# Hyperledger Fabric Connection issues with Docker Swarm on GCP instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, hyperledger-fabric, docker-swarm, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have created a Hyperledger Fabric (version 2.2) network consisting of four nodes, with two nodes hosted on AWS instances and the other two on GCP instances. I have connected these nodes using a Docker Swarm network with public IP addresses.

All the Docker services for the nodes were up and able to connect to each other. However, when I tried to install Chaincode on the GCP peer instance, I encountered the error message as follows:

`Error getting endorser client for install: context deadline exceeded.`

Additionally, the GCP peer logs indicated a TLS handshake failure.

Furthermore, when I attempted to add a new peer node on the GCP instance, I received the error message as `Client TLS handshake failed after 10.669562ms with error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority( This error may be related to "x509: ECDSA verification failure)` during the attempt install the chaincode.

I suspect that these errors are caused by connection issues with Docker on GCP instances since I am not experiencing any issues on the AWS instances.

Is there anything specific that needs to be configured to establish connectivity between GCP and AWS instances in this context?